# IOS/Objective-C: Using Protocols with Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

I am new to protocols and have basic question.

If the protocol specifies an object does this mean it can only be used in an object of the same class type?

Specifically, I want to use the following protocol that specifies an NSObject in UITableViewCell.  Is this possible?

```
@protocol DownloadHelperDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)didCompleteDownloadForURL:(NSString *)url withData:(NSMutableData *)data;

@end
```

I want to use it an a tableview cell but the following is not working, probably because it is a UITableViewCell, not an NSObject.

```
@interface IDTVCell : UITableViewCell<DownloadHelperDelegate>
```

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to handle this case.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: `NSObject` is the lowest-level protocol that a protocol can inherit from, much like it is for Objective-C classes.  It will be fine for what you want.

Comment: What are the error messages you are getting?

As a side note: All objects in objective-c inherit from NSObject. This means that UITableViewCell is actually also an NSObject.

Comment: can you kindly explain, how it is not working? and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: 'Cannot Find Protocol Declaration for DownloadHelperDelegate'  I have imported the class with the protocol and also added an @class IDTVCell in the class declaring the protocol

Comment: The symbol listed in the angle brackets (<>'s) after the protocol name is the super-protocol, if you will, of the new protocol which is being declared.  What it means is that anyone adopting the new protocol must also implement the protocol listed in the angle brackets.  As UITableViewCell is a descendent of NSObject (the class), it also implements NSObject the protocol.

Comment: I should mention that the class that is declaring a protocol is a category.  Don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: Where are you declaring the protocol ? In the IDTVCell class or somewhere else ?

Comment: somewhere else in category

Answer (score 0):

Above code looks fine, `UITableViewCell` also has `NSObject` at the start of its inheritance chain. May be you have conformed to the protocol but haven't implemented the required method (as in your case method of the protocol is not `@optional`) of protocol so it is giving error.

Implement below method in your `IDTVCell` class

```
-(void)didCompleteDownloadForURL:(NSString *)url withData:(NSMutableData *)data;
```

Comment: Ok. Error must lie elsewhere

Comment: is it giving compile time error? i am talking about your original code

Comment: Is the error on this line `@interface IDTVCell : UITableViewCell<DownloadHelperDelegate>` ?

Comment: Try adding `@protocol DownloadHelperDelegate;` directly bellow your import line and above the line with the error. Since you're importing the protocol it should work nicely

Comment: That helped some.  No longer red error but instead yellow warning "Cannot  find protocol definition for DownloadHelperDelegate

Comment: Here is the definition of the protocol in the source file of the imported category.  It is not in the header file.  @protocol DownloadHelperDelegate <NSObject>-(void)didCompleteDownloadForURL:(NSString *)url withData:(NSMutableData *)data;@end

Comment: i think you haven't implemented the delegate method in your class which conforms to the protocol

Comment: @Usama not quite because the warning would print "missing methods from protocol" vs "cannot find protocol"

Comment: @user1904273 if you're not importing the file that contains the protocol, .h or .m, you must, MUST move the protocol in the file you're importing. It's best to be in the header file, I would think

Comment: I have imported it and then follow up with @protocol line you suggested directly below. This changed red error to warning but still have warning and delegate method is not firing.

Comment: you can setup a git repo (or use dropbox) with you code sample, only then anyone will be able to help as your explanation is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You need to import class where you are declaring that protocol and then use in uitableviewCell subclass